# Emulsification and liquid liquid surface reaction

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

[image]

What will happen if I skip the addition of surfactant?

will the reaction happen only at the surface of the parent liquids?

Comment: If you do not add the surfactant you will not get an emulsion and the mixture will revert to a 2 phase system after stirring. Some reaction is still possible at the phase boundary but it will be orders of magnitude slower than it would be in the emulsion.

Comment: Yeah! Can you suggest some economically viable mixture components on which I may perform the above surface reaction, i.e the reaction which may occur at the 2 phase boundary! Thanks

Comment: It depends on what reaction you are attempting to do. I'm a synthetic organic chemist so my "go to" reagents for 2 phase reactions are tetra-alkyl ammonium salts such as tetrabutylammonium hydrogen sulfate

Comment: Basically I want to mimic a different system by these reactions! The only condition is that the bottom phase should be aqueous. And then the top phase maybe something which is miscible in oil (like Si oil or vegetable oil etc.).

Comment: I want to perform a surface reaction such that the new product which forms at the surface, goes on to diffuse in the 2 phases and thereby changing the thero-physical properties of these 2 phases near the reaction zone ( i.e the interface).

Comment: 2 weeks back I was considering these reactions to mimic my system. You may have a look @https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/125179/liquids-which-may-dissolve-polyacrylic-acid?noredirect=1#comment239534_125179

Answer (score 1):

It depends a bit on what you are trying to achieve :

If you are trying to form an emulsion, for example a homopolymer emulsion resin solution, then the emulsifier is absolutely necessary.

If you are trying to extract a water soluble entity from the oil/powder phase then an emulsifier may actually interfere with the process - at least in terms of post extraction separation.

The supplied image suggests that you are trying to form a "stable" dispersion - in which case an emulsifier (or emulsifiers) of the correct type and appropriate HLB value at the correct concentration will be needed. Appropriate physical energy will also be required.

Comment: I want to just perform a surface reaction between 2 bulk phases! i.e I don't want to make emulsification droplets and just analyze the reaction film happening at the surface!